# File transfer from one host to another host through PHP and cURL

Tags: php, curl

I want to transfer a file from one host to another through PHP and cURL. This is my code :

```
<?php
    $source = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&export=download';
    $fh = fopen( basename( $source ), 'w' );
    $ch = curl_init( $source );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fh );
    curl_exec( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );
    fclose( $fh );
    echo 'yes';
?>
```

An empty file is created on the destination host with the name : uc?id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&export=download.

I have 2 questions :

1. Why does it show zero volume on the destination host?
2. The name of the file on the source host is index.html, how can I change it from uc?id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&export=download to index.html when transferring to the destination host?

I hope you help. Thank you.

Comment: _"Why does it show zero volume on the destination host?"_ - most likely, because the _source_ host didn't actually send any data. I think it is pretty safe to assume that Google wants those links to be used by "real people" only, and has measures in place to detect "bots."

Comment: Although, such a URL redirects multiple times - and I don't know if `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` is set true by default, or not. Try adding it, and see if you get a different result then. (If so, my assumption that they detected you as a "bot", would be wrong then.)

Comment: _"The name of the file on the source host is index.html"_ - the final URL in the redirection chain will contain a `Content-Disposition` header, looking something like this, `attachment; filename="index.html"; filename*=UTF-8''index.html` - so you will have to capture that response header, and extract the file name from it. (You won't be able to use `CURLOPT_FILE` then, because you can't get the name, before you made the request. So you will have to get the cURL response, and then write it to a file of the name you determined _after_ the request, yourself.)

Comment: I was able to transfer the file correctly using the file_get_contents() function, but allow_url_fopen is not enabled in most hosts, and I am looking for a method that is possible in most hosts, so I want to use cURL to do it, what do you think?

Comment: file_get_contents follows redirects by default, as I said I am not sure what the default for cURL is - so try and explicitly instruct it to do so. If that doesn't change anything, try and send a `User-Agent` header as well.

Comment: A question outside the discussion, is there a function that is active in most hostings and can be used to transfer a file from one host to another?

Comment: Not really. cURL is the go-to, for broadest support. Some file system functions like `copy` can use an HTTP URL for the source as well - but those are also dependent on allow_url_fopen.

Comment: CBroe, how patiently you answered me, thank you for taking the time to answer me, I also tested the copy() function and it was ok, but as you say, it depends on allow_url_fopen.

Comment: @CBroe The default is false, just like the CLI `curl`.

Comment: For downloading a file from Google Drive, the normal way is to have Client ID and Client Secret on hand (so as to make API calls to Google Drive) and then use `$GoogleDriveApi->GetFileMediaContent` to get the file contents and then use PHP `file_put_contents` function to save the file. I think if you google search `Download File from Google Drive using PHP` you can find a couple of code examples [For non-google drive, yes you may try using fopen / fwrite / curl /file_get_contents / file_put_contents etc.]